# What plant or weed is this?

Tags: weeds

Its about 6 ft tall, not sure what it is, want to tear it out.

[image]

Comment: Any pictures of buds/flowers?  This looks like Amaranth, great garden plant to collect seeds, birds...did you look at the list they say make this a duplicate question?  6' is pretty big but looks like there is a bit of shade as well that might cause the height.

Comment: @stormy, This one is the only one with that white leaf, yellow bud flower... most are just those green leaves.  Maybe just a few are 6ft tall.. most I would say is probably 4-5 ft, I'm 5'8 myself.

Comment: What a mystery...Michelle and Bamboo are flummoxed!  I doubt that the little yellow flowers are associated with the plant I think looks like Amaranth...there are probably 3 or 4 different plants in your photo.  Otherwise I am totally flummoxed as well! Grin!  Please pull apart the individual plants and take more pictures...perhaps explain what it is you would like to do with your property, where you are finding these plants.  Thanks!!

Comment: The plant in best focus/lighting conditions in the lower right hand side definitely looks like Lambsquarters: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19610/can-someone-identify-this/19612#19612  6 Feet would be within it's capacity for growth. The little flowers definitely are an entirely different plant

Answer (score 1):

Well, the flower stems and flowers look exactly like Galinsoga quadriradiata (link below), commonly known as Shaggy Soldier, Quick Weed, Peruvian Daisy, take your pick - but that usually only gets about 2 feet, and the leaves don't seem quite right on this plant. Could there be more than one type of plant growing together, and the flowers we can see are not part of the main foliage that's visible, but simply intermingled?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galinsoga_quadriradiata

The foliage actually resembles one of the Chenopodiums, possibly Chenopodium album or C. murale (amaranth family), but that isn't usually as tall and has an inflorescence at the top for flowers which are not at all daisy like in form. C. album pictured here:-

http://www.apatita.com/herbario/Amaranthaceae/Chenopodium_album.html

I just noticed another question of yours about a weed that isn't a tomato (pokeweed) - I'd recommend you do a bit more weeding about the place, since the two plants in this question are also considered weeds, on the assumption you didn't actually plant them.

Comment: I agree that it looks like two separate plants growing together and the plant with the larger leaves (the ones that are silvery in the foreground) is likely an amaranth. I think that the flower is some variety of fleabane, though (Erigeron Annuus). the appearance seems a better match to me than Peruvian Daisy, and it can get nearly 60 inches tall, so the size would be a better match.

Comment: Sorry, Michelle, defo not Erigeron annuus - that has a ray formation of white petals round the yellow centre - Galinsoga has 5 groups of 3 fused petals ranged round the yellow centre with gaps inbetween, and that's what I'm seeing in the picture above (when magnified). Plus, who knows how tall the white flowered plant is, if its separate from the other....

Comment: Ooh, you are right - I hadn't magnified before commenting. They looked like a ray formation to me before that. Never mind!

Comment: Me too, I assumed they were normal daisy type - not clear in the pic without enlarging

Comment: I agree that we're looking at more than one plant here. The leaf shape and even coat waxy crystals on the leaves make me agree with Bamboo that the "bulk" of the vegetation visible is some kind of Chenopodium.